# Relocate to vs. or Relocate into

Tags: subjects

I'd like to get advise on this!

Ireland intends to relocate 3,205 refugees to their territory. 
OR
Ireland intends to relocates 920 refugees into their territory.

Answer (score 1):

[*To relocate*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/relocate?s=t) is to exchange one fixed point for another, not motion into a space like a thunderstorm moving from the North Atlantic *into* Ireland. So Ireland plans to relocate refugees to/in/within their territory.

Using the name of singular name of a country as a notional plural — *their* territory — is British usage. American English would use *its*.

Comment: Quite and what did your search engines and dictionaries leave unsaid about the differnce between "in" and "into"? Thankfully, that about American and British differences isn't yet true and at least most of us Brits still get that right, however far we might slip in sports.